# Get authorization code with Google Sign-In

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-signin

I need to obtain `auth code` from YouTube-api to pass it to server-side which then tries to retrieve `access token` using the `auth code`. Is there any way of getting `auth code` with Google Sign-In library?

Right now i can only get `accessToken` on device:

```
val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
if (result.isSuccess) {
    // Get the account from the sign in result
    val account = result.signInAccount

    // Store the account from the result
    mAccount = account?.account

    ...

    // Asynchronously access the People API for the account
    val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton(YOUTUBE_SCOPE))
    credential.selectedAccount = mAccount

    val token = credential.token
}
```

And I have found no way of getting `auth code` without using **`webview`**.

Comment: There's a whole page dedicated to [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization in Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) which supports [server-side flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps), [client-side flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps), [installed application flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps), and [device flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/devices).

Comment: @noogui, yes and "Google SIgn-In" is a suggested alternative for "installed application flow" which I'm trying to use. The question is there any way of getting the authorization code (not access token) using this "Google SIgn-In" lib?

Comment: @cora32 did you found a way? Seems that is impossible.